# I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my laptop. I am unable to connect to the Internet by wifi or cable

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, internet, ethernet

But after installation I am unable to connect to my modem by ether cable or wifi. I have tried to search for information about this but unable to find anything. I am very new to this and not sure what to do. I have tried `ip a` but it does not give me a ipv4 address. It also does not recognize `enp3s4f1` or `enp3s4f0`. Also tried `sudo ethtool -s enp3s4f1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off` but I get `sudo: ethtool: command not found`. When I check network under wired it says that the cable is unplug even though it is plugged in. Tried `/etc/network/interfaces` but got permission denied. Used `sudo lshw -C network` and it recognized my cable port and wifi card. When I used `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` it said no such file or directory.

I have a COMPAQ Presario CQ56 that I used Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit at one time and had no problems connecting to the internet with either wifi or cable. This is the same computer that I am trying to get 18.04.3 to run on. After trying `ifconfig -a' I am told to use` sudo apt install net-tools`. When I use` sudo apt install net-tools`with my installation disk in cd drive I get`Package net-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`. Where do I get the package!

Comment: Try shutting down computer, remove cable, reboot and then connect cable.  Is possible 18.04 uses a new updated driver for your wired connection.  Net-tools usually downloaded over internet, which you don't have yet.  Show what lshw gave.

Answer (score 0):

I found the net-tools package and down loaded it to a USB. I then installed it on my laptop and it now works 100% to connect to the internet.